# With Instancio, how to ignore a superclass private property

Tags: java, unit-testing, instancio

I'm got a class `B` that extends an `abstract` class `A`.  Class `A` has a private member that's initialized in the constructor.

```java
public abstract class A {

  private String _dtoType;
  private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  public A() {
     this._dtoType = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  public String getDtoType() { return this._dtoType; }
  public String getUuid() { return this.uuid; }

}
```

```java
public class B extends A {

  private String accountNumber;
  private String name;

  private C propC;
  private List<D> propDs;

  public B() {
     super();
  }

}
```

Assume that both `C` and `D` extend `A`, too.

I want to ignore both `_dtoType` and `uuid` for all classes.  Say, if I'm creating an instance of `B`:

```java
B item = Instancio.of(B.class)
                .generate(field(B::getAccountNumber), gen -> gen.text().pattern("#d#d#d#d#d#d#d#d"))
                .ignore(all(field("_dtoType")))
                .ignore(all(field("uuid")))
                .subtype(all(C.class), C.class)
                .subtype(all(D.class), D.class)
                .create();
```

But, I get an error:

```
Reason: invalid field '_dtoType' for class B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have to be specific and reference the abstract class `A` in the ignore:

```java
                .ignore(all(field(A.class, "_dtoType")))
                .ignore(all(field(A.class,"uuid")))
```

Comment: When only field name is given, `field("uuid")`, Instancio assumes that the field belongs to the class being created (in this case class `B`). If the field belongs to the parent class, the solution is to specify the class explicitly, as you've correctly outlined in your answer.